# Krull dimension localization with coefficients

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over an integral domain, $A$. Let $s = a\prod_{1\leq i \leq n}{x_i}^{\alpha_i}$, $a \in A$. What is the Krull dimension of $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]_s$?

Comment: Not so sure witout assumptions on $A$. The only general result I can see in Bourbaki is $\;\dim S^{-1}A\le\dim A$ for any mutiplicative subset $S$.

Comment: Letting $s=at$, where $t$ is the product of the variables as you have, and letting $B=A_a$, $A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_s=B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_t$. So, with standard hypothesis, it follows that the dimension of your ring $n+\dim B$.

Comment: @Mohan I wonder what do you mean by "standard hypothesis"?

Comment: The standard hypothesis= Noetherian with finite Krull dimension.